# What is the actual lowest possible positive REAL number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, data-integrity

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)  that the range of REAL numbers is - 3.40E + 38 to -1.18E - 38, 0 and 1.18E - 38 to 3.40E + 38. Apparently the true lower limit is much lower. The following script populates a REAL column with 1.401298E-45:

```
CREATE TABLE a
  (
    r1 REAL NULL ,
    r2 REAL NULL ,
    r3 REAL NULL
  ) ;
GO
INSERT  INTO a
        ( r1, r2 )
VALUES  ( 1.18E-37, 10 ) ;
GO
DECLARE @i INT ;
SET @i = 1 ;

WHILE @i < 20 
  BEGIN ;

    UPDATE  a
    SET     r1 = r1 / r2 ;

    SELECT  r1 ,
            r2
    FROM    a ;

    SET @i = @i + 1 ;

  END ;
GO
DROP TABLE a ;

r1            r2
------------- -------------
1.18E-38      10

(snip)

r1            r2
------------- -------------
1.401298E-45  10
```

Can anyone tell me what is the actual lowest possible positive number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minimum positive (subnormal) single-precision floating-point value is 2<sup>−149</sup> ≈ 1.4 × 10<sup>−45</sup>. The minimum positive normal value is 2<sup>−126</sup> ≈ 1.18 × 10<sup>−38</sup> ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)).

```
DECLARE
    @r1 real = POWER(2e0, -126),
    @r2 real = POWER(2e0, -23)

SELECT
    @r1,
    @r2,
    @r1 * @r2,
    CONVERT(binary(4), @r1 * @r2);
```

For double-precision, the minimum positive *subnormal* is:

```
DECLARE @r1 float = POWER(2e0, -1075);

SELECT @r1, CONVERT(binary(8), @r1);
```